# Set some trigger that removes rows older than few minutes from DB with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data

I have a Java app on Spring Boot with Cassandra DB, where I'm writing to DB Person entities.
Each row of person in DB must be deleted when get 5 minute old, so the concept is easy:

Some person is added to DB with timestamp and this person must be removed after exactly 5 minutes.

The only idea that comes to mind is setting Spring Scheduler which runs every second and checks every row if it's expired and if it is, then it is deleted.

Comment: Why must it be deleted exactly after 5 minutes?

Comment: for simplicity i wrote that it would be people entities but it won't. It's gonna be different (more complicated to describe) entites which 5 minutes life is reasonable

Comment: You didn't answer the question (I didn't ask anything about people entities). Why must it be **deleted** exactly after 5 minutes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using Cassandra as a DB you could leverage the Cassandra TTL feature.

> During data insertion, you have to specify 'ttl' value in seconds. 'ttl' value is the time to live value for the data. After that particular amount of time, data will be automatically removed.

TTL syntax in cql would be like

```
INSERT INTO person (name, age) VALUES ('ExampleName', '39') USING TTL 300;
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of running a Spring Scheduler every second, you could easily create a timer task after each record and using TimerTask(Core java), you create a task that will execute after the set interval and delete the record.
PFB some useful link and example:

https://www.baeldung.com/java-timer-and-timertask